# Need to change from Visual studio 2015 to 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-3.5, .net-4.5

I´m having the following problem.
I developed a aplication in visual studio 2015. But my company have bought a TORADEX pc, and it runs a Windows CE that can only be programmed with visual studio 2008.
The project is done in 2015 but i need it in 2008.
I tried to open the solution in visual studio 2008 but it doesn´t works
Im working in C#, developed a software with 4.5 framework but i need the compact 3.5. That´s why i´m moving to VS 2008
What can i do ?
Thank you all
Sorry if my doubt is silly

Comment: Why don't you create a solution for 2008 and add all the files and settings from the one of 2015? I don't think you can port the solution automatically from 2015 to 2008, at least not reliably.

Comment: I have tried this, but the forms are not recognized by the older version

Comment: Then you have to add more information in the question regarding what programming language you use and everything else needed so someone else can understand better the scenario and help you out

Comment: I´ve added some extra descriptions @FrankS101

Comment: Compact Framework 3.5 is completely a different platform. So your quickest approach is to recreate the project and cut/paste useful code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a solution created in visual studio 2015 with an earlier version of visual studio. There have been a number of changes to the solution and project formats since 2008.